# How to test a mocked method that is used as a called function parameter -in a curry function- and not as a direct called function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, logging, mocking, currying

Here is the code to be tested, a small logger module, built as a composed object, this object has keys that are represented by curry functions. These curry functions have as first parameter a method that actually implements the method to be called (that requires a test).

Basically I would like to check that `console.log` or `console.info` are called.

logger.ts

```
const log = (logFn: () => void) => (message: any) => {
  logFn(message)
}

const logger = {
  debug: log(console.log),
  info: log(console.info)
}

export default logger
```

logger.spec.ts

```
import logger from './logger'

describe('logger', () => {
  describe('debug', () => {
    it('sets a text as log output', () => {
      const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log')
      const text = 'Export is working properly'

      logger.debug(text)

      expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // failure
      expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(text) // failure


      console.log(text)

      expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // success
      expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(text) // success
   })
  })
})
```

But what happens is that, if I call `console.log` directly in my `logger.ts`, the test detects that the method is invoked, while, if I call my module method `logFn` that invokes indirectly `console.log` through a curry function, then the test does not detect it. I guess that the level of mocking is not reaching the proper scope. Anyway question is, is there a way to manage it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the mocks are working correctly, because if you wrap the call `console.log` in an arrow function like `debug: log((message: any) => console.log(message))`, the test passes.

Comment: ah I know in this way it works, but my code is different, I've a curry function, and the method `console.log` is passed through the functions via the parameter `logFn`.
so question is still unanswered to me. or am I missing something?
to be clear. I want this to be true `logger.debug(text); expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(text)`